# Не удаеться найти главный класс

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с проблемой, указанной в названии темы. В интернете искал ответ, но, к сожалению, не могу решить проблему.
Вот код:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Keyboard extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

JTextArea ta;
JButton digits[]=new JButton[10];
JButton a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,point,comma,enter,space,backspace,shift;
JLabel l1; 
public void init(){
  l1 = new JLabel("Enter your message here: ");
  add(l1);
  ta = new JTextArea();
  add(ta);
  GridLayout gl=new GridLayout(5,12);
  setLayout(gl);
  for (int amount = 0; amount < 10; amount++){
      digits[amount] = new JButton(""+amount);
  }
  a = new JButton("a");
  b = new JButton("b");
  c = new JButton("c");
  d = new JButton("d");
  e = new JButton("e");
  f = new JButton("f");
  g = new JButton("g");
  h = new JButton("h");
  i = new JButton("i");
  j = new JButton("g");
  k = new JButton("k");
  l = new JButton("l");
  m = new JButton("m");
  n = new JButton("n");
  o = new JButton("o");
  p = new JButton("p");
  q = new JButton("q");
  r = new JButton("r");
  s = new JButton("s");
  t = new JButton("t");
  u = new JButton("u");
  v = new JButton("v");
  w = new JButton("w");
  x = new JButton("x");
  y = new JButton("y");
  z = new JButton("z");
  point = new JButton(".");
  comma = new JButton(",");
  enter = new JButton("enter");
  space = new JButton("space");
  backspace = new JButton("backspace");
  shift = new JButton("shift");
  for (int amount = 0; amount < 10; amount++){
      add(digits[amount]);
  }
  add(a);
  add(b);
  add(c);
  add(d);
  add(e);
  add(f);
  add(g);
  add(h);
  add(i);
  add(j);
  add(k);
  add(l);
  add(m);
  add(n);
  add(o);
  add(p);
  add(q);
  add(r);
  add(s);
  add(t);
  add(u);
  add(v);
  add(w);
  add(x);
  add(y);
  add(z);
  add(point);
  add(comma);
  add(enter);
  add(space);
  add(backspace);
  add(shift);
  for (int amount = 0; amount < 10; amount++){
      digits[amount].addActionListener(this);
  }
  a.addActionListener(this);
  b.addActionListener(this);
  c.addActionListener(this);
  d.addActionListener(this);
  e.addActionListener(this);
  f.addActionListener(this);
  g.addActionListener(this);
  h.addActionListener(this);
  i.addActionListener(this);
  j.addActionListener(this);
  k.addActionListener(this);
  l.addActionListener(this);
  m.addActionListener(this);
  n.addActionListener(this);
  o.addActionListener(this);
  p.addActionListener(this);
  q.addActionListener(this);
  r.addActionListener(this);
  s.addActionListener(this);
  t.addActionListener(this);
  u.addActionListener(this);
  v.addActionListener(this);
  w.addActionListener(this);
  x.addActionListener(this);
  y.addActionListener(this);
  z.addActionListener(this);
  point.addActionListener(this);
  comma.addActionListener(this);
  enter.addActionListener(this);
  space.addActionListener(this);
  backspace.addActionListener(this);
  shift.addActionListener(this);
  setBackground(Color.yellow);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
     String ac = ae.getActionCommand();
      switch (ac) {
          case "point":
              ta.setText(ta.getText()+".");
              break;
          case "comma":
              ta.setText(ta.getText()+",");
              break;
          case "enter":
              ta.setText(ta.getText()+"\n");
              break;
          case "space":
              ta.setText(ta.getText()+" ");
              break;
          case "backspace":
              ta.setText(ta.getText()+"\b");
              break;
          case "shift":
              ta.setText(ta.getText()+"////////////////////////");
              break;
          default:
              ta.setText(ta.getText()+String.valueOf(ac));
              break;
      }  
} 
}
```

Посмотрите, пожалуйста. что не так, и скажите, как правильно создавать подобный проект, если ошибка в создании. Говорю сразу, с апплетами доселе не имел дела. Код писал в NetBeans 8.1

Comment: Большая часть кода вообще никак к теме вопроса не относится - сократите его. Ну и попробуйте, что ли, сделать где-нить метод `main` коий и должен указывать на главный класс в программе.

Comment: Опыта работы с апплетами у меня нету, но я читал, что у них нету класса main

Comment: а код привел весь, чтобы потом не возникали вопросы где он

Comment: Возможно, вы не так запускаете. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29297405/3212712

Comment: Да, спасибо.уже нашел этот пункт но теперь,пишет applet not initialized

Comment: проблема в коде, наверное, но из за незнания специфики апплетов, не могу понять проблему

Comment: Как вы его запускаете? его из браузера надо запускать

Comment: апплет вивером, раньше создавал один. но спомощью формочек, так он запускался в вивере

Comment: проблема в том,что при использовании формочек код прописываеться сам ведь, и ты заполняешь только события. А у меня задание без формочек.

Comment: очень нужна помощь, ведь задание на курсовую

Comment: "applet not initialized" у вас потому, что программа падает. В консоли netbeans выводится исключение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По идее у Вас должно выкидывать исключение `java.lang.NullPointerException` т.к Вы не инициализировали массив:

```
JButton digits[];
```

объявите его как

```
JButton digits[]=new JButton[10];
```

и проблема отпадет

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Keyboard.init(Keyboard.java:16)
 at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:434)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: да,есть такое исключение.

Comment: а могли бы Вы подкорректировать мой код, а то выводит не клавиатуру, а одну кнопку

Comment: если Вас не затруднит)

Comment: изменил код, но не могу разобраться с компоновкой

Comment: @MuscledBoy компоновки выполняються через систему макетов(layout)(JavaFX в этом отношении очень гибкий куча вариантов, хоть CSS используйтие). Достойный туториал от [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/jfxpub-layout.htm)

Comment: @MuscledBoy и вдогонку во первых автоматизируйте добовление обектов, не плодите простынь буз нужды И во вторых вы можете не использовть аплет а наследовать свой класс / или создать экземпляр класса JFrame(Frame для  java.awt.) и добавлять обекты в него (это  путь через видимо привычный Вам метод main)

Comment: понял, спасибо.

Comment: хотя,один момент. Что вы имеете в виду под автоматизировать добавление объектов? Например для цифр я сделал, а для букв ведь не так просто. Второе: если поставить панель и бокслейаут будет лучше?